# Am I being double natted?

Tags: networking, routing

When I try to port forward on my router, nothing gets through making me think I am double natted?

when I go to www.whatismyip.com I see the public ip referenced below but when I do a tracert, it seems to get a private ip quite early on as noted below.

What do you think is wrong?

```
tracert 8.8.8.8
  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  OpenWrt.lan [192.168.1.1]
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  soOnAndSoFortth.net [148.77.1XX.XX]
  3    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.2.200.1
  4     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  148.77.35.50
  5     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  148.77.24.157
  6     2 ms     2 ms     2 ms  64.15.3.150
  7     4 ms     3 ms     3 ms  64.15.6.8
  8     4 ms     3 ms     4 ms  72.14.215.203
  9     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  108.170.225.8
 10     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  172.253.72.117
 11     3 ms     3 ms     3 ms  dns.google [8.8.8.8]
```

[image: openwrt and what is my ip]

Comment: as far as I know, you don't get double NATed, NAT is something you do to yourself!! (though there is ISP NAT but I can't comment much on that.. I guess there you'd get NATTd!) but still you wouldn't get double NATTed,  you'd potentially get NATTd by the ISP  and then you might then NAT yourself.. leading you to BE double NATTd but that's not really getting double NATd 'cos you did at least one of those yourself if there is double NAT going on!

Comment: I’d start with Is soonandsoforth.com your router?  If it is and you have paid for a public IP and it is a public IP then the public should be able to reach it. Can they ping it?

Comment: Since you’re using OpenWRT, you can easily check your router’s WAN IP address. Please provide the first two octets.

Comment: Nothing us wrong, and you are not being double NATted. The 10.2.200 IP is not indicative of NAT in this case and is just being used by an internal router - this does not mean your connection is being batted at or through that point - it just means that that router speaks to other routers in rfc1918 space which is permissible even in the absense of NAT.

Answer (score 2):

Double NAT is likely not involved. What is happening at hop 3 is that you are connecting through a router interface that does not have a public IP. As you already likely have a public IP (as per hop 2), its just the router which does not have a public IP.

It is entirely practical for internal routers without a public IP to route between 2 routers with public IPs.

Similarly, if you were being routed via an ISP NAT, it would more likely be in the 100.x.x.x range as that is set aside for carrier grade NAT.

It is impossible to totally rule out double NAT - you can even NAT public IPs, but it is unlikely this is the case as this kind of setup wpuld be quite unusual in an ISP environment as it serves little valid purpose here.

Comment: couldn't that "public ip" be shared though?

Comment: @Dave84981645 technically it could, but in practice its highly unlikely. It is the LAN facing IP rather then the WAN facing one - I can think I'd few good reasons for this, nine which would apply to an ISP. If the ISP were doing NAT, they would likely need a pool of valid IP addresses to adequately do connection tracking. This would not be on the LAN interface.

Comment: The way to find out for sure would be to log into your router and see what address I'd associated with the WAN interface (the interface of the default gateway). My guess us its a public IP. If its a private IP then there is likely double NAT (I'd bet its not a private IP though)  If its a public IP, hit a few sites which reflect your IP address - www.whatismyip.com is generally a good bet. If the IP of your WAN interface matches the result of these remote sites, there is no double NAT.

Answer (score 0):

The third hop `10.2.200.1` is a private network address. The next hop `148.77.35.50` belong to "Cablevision Systems", is this possibly your ISP?

If yes, and given the ping times, my guess would be that your ISP uses [carrier grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT), and these are the internal hops.

Which means you can make port forward settings as much as you like, your ISP just doesn't route anything incoming to you. At least in the EU, this is quite common (because IPv4 address have run out). It's also common that you can make a more expensive contract (often a "business contract") that gives you a public IPv4 address that gets routed to you.

Comment: I don't think this is correct - For a start, the address space used in hop 3 is not in 100.64.0.0/10 - but more importantly, if CGN was being used, it would seem highly, highly unusual that hop 2 would be a public IP adddress - specifically I can't see how you would have an RFC1918 on your WAN interface [ ie ext interface of device on hop 1] with your gateway being on a public IP.   While this can be made to work with extra routes on the router, I can't see that being a common deployment method for end user equipment because it will cause headaches and can be better done on router 2.

Comment: note I added more detail about my public ip address --> further my ISP is not a normal one, it's a poorly managed place that buys capacity from cablevision and resells it using a wide variety of weird/bad networking equipment - they've periodically had to "reenable" my ability to get forwarded ports in the past (I'm still waiting on them to do it this time)

Comment: "it's a poorly managed place that buys capacity from cablevision". Ah, that explains things. Yes, they have to "reenable" this, and fix their setup. Whatever it is they do.